# Customized preprocessor in SVM model for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, svm

I'm implementing a `SVM` model for a **text classification** problem. I use `SVC` classifier with the vectorizer: `CountVectorizer` which has a `preprocessor` parameter which can take a customized function.

`CountVectorizer(preprocessor=mp.prepro,analyzer="word",max_df=0.6,min_df=3,ngram_range=(1,7))`

Trying to reduce the number of features I have built my own **preprocessor** in which I do the following tasks:

- Assign all **months names** the label "month_exp"
- Assign all **week days names** the label "week_exp"
- Assign all **time expression** *(12:10a.m.)* the label "time_exp"
- Assign all **digit expression** with *n* digits the label "dig_i"
- Apply a Stemmer.

Moreover I have imported a dictionary and using it I have checked if each word belongs to English language. If it doesn't hold I assign to this word the label "uknw_exp".

I have done all this because I think that is important that my model is capable to recognize these expressions for the classification problem.
So I want help because I don't know if my reasoning is right or not.

- If is right, how can I improve it?
- Is there any better preprocessor pre-cooked that I can Implement?
- Could it be a good idea try to join this method with word embeddings?

Thanks for the help!